# Reading file and print it in hex format really slow

Tags: java, performance, beginner, file

I'm trying to read a file and print its byte in hex form, using the below code. The code those it but i think optimization can be done to make it read and print faster, because if i remove the print the timestamp is 53ms+/-[image: Without Print], 
but printing, it takes 18 minutes to read a file of 29mb.
[image: With print]

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class cOnvert {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    try {
        try (RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile("filePath", "r")) {
            FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
            MappedByteBuffer buffer = inChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, inChannel.size());
            String set;
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {
                byte read = buffer.get();
                set = (String.format("%02X ", (byte) read));
                System.out.print(set);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long elapsedTimeInMillis = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert((endTime - startTime), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    System.out.println("Total elapsed time: " + elapsedTimeInMillis + " ms");
}
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to the console is incredibly slow.... it also bit me in the past :)

Console is not really meant to print such big data anyway. What's your use case ?

---

### Performance tuning

To reduce the impact on performance, you should try to reduce the number of call to `System.out.print(set)` to only one, at the end of the run....

You may end with a very big `String` however, so you should use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Combining both those things should reduce the time taken by your application by a very noticeable amount and you should end up with something looking like this :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// some more code
try (RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile("filePath", "r")) {
        FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer buffer = inChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, inChannel.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {
            final byte read = buffer.get();
            sb.append((String.format("%02X ", read)));
            sb.append("\n");
        }
}
```

To ((very) slighlty) improve performance you may give your StringBuilder a big starting size like this :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1_000_000);
```

Of course, you should prefer a well named constant over this ugly 1000000.

### Other things in the code

Now that we are done with the performance aspect :
1. the name aFile is not really good looking IMO.
2. there is two nested try clause within each other but it's useless here.
3. please never user empty catch block :'(

After all those tweaks : it takes my computer 1 minute and a half to read a 28.5 mb file.

Comment: Thank you worked like magic @Ronan.
Kindly check [http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.github.javadev%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hexeditor%22] The author claims to be able to read over 5 exabyte of file,  how did they achieve it with out memory leaks.

Comment: Also it doesn't read a big file, i tried it on 120mb and i OutOfMemory error.

Comment: @kingamada sorry didn't saw your messages.  Not really sure honestly :p StringBuilder won't be able to store a file over ~2 Go anyway so exabyte is obviously out of the question.
By having an array of string you may theorically store millions elements of 2 Go string... but you'd never have enough RAM for this....
To help with your problem that is within the mb realm : launch your application with the xmx argument : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms